# An issue with itertools.groupby in Python

Tags: python

Why the following code return two **False** pairs?

```
from itertools import groupby

content = '1\t2\t3\n4\t5\t\n7\t8\t9'

result = groupby((line.split('\t') for line in content.splitlines()),
                 key=lambda x: x[2] == '')

for k, v in result:
    print '--->', k, id(k)
    print list(v)
```

The result as following shown

```
---> False 505954168
[['1', '2', '3']]
---> True 505954192
[['4', '5', '']]
---> False 505954168
[['7', '8', '9']]
```

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: I expect all False items are in a single group

Comment: A dictionary would be the way to group, groupby only works for data that is ordered

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

> makes an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the
>   iterable. ... **It generates a break or new group every time the value of the key function changes (which is why it is usually necessary to have sorted the data using the same key function).**

Emphasis added.

You'll need to sort your input

```
genexp = (line.split('\t') for line in content.splitlines())
key = lambda x: x[2] == ''

result = groupby(sorted(genexp, key=key), key=key) # Note: same key function
```

or write your own grouping function. Frankly, it's not that hard:

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for x in genexp:
    dd[key(x)].append(x)
result = dd.items()
```

Comment: dicts are also more efficient than sorting